# Is there any way to compare one given row in a data table with other rows withing a group?

Tags: r, data.table, compare, row

I would like to compare one given row with every single row in another column within a specific group (for this specific case second) in data table. For instance suppose I have the following data table

```
>dt<- data.table(bSIDE = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
            EX = c(1,3,9,14,1,3,5,14,1,2),
            second=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
            PRICE1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,127.47,127.47,127.47,127.47,NA,NA),
       PRICE2=c(127.49,127.48,127.58,127.46,NA,NA,NA,NA,127.48,127.48))
```

I would like to compare the first row in column PRICE1 within the group second=0 and EX=1 with every single row in column PRICE2 within second=0, such that if PRICE1: 127.47 is larger at least once than the non NAs price in column 2 (within the group second=0), then it should create a dummy with value of 1, otherwise should take the value of 0. In this case, in no moment this condition is filled, so for EX1 within the second=0, it should create a dummy=0. This procedure should be done for every EX within group second=0.And the same applies when it come to compare PRICE2 with PRICE1, but in this case the condition is reversed, such that if PRICE2 for one given EX within second=0 is lower at least once than any row in PRICE1 within second=0 than it should create a dummy taking the value of 1 and 0 otherwise. Thus, I would like to get the following:

```
> objective<- data.table(bSIDE = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),
            EX = c(1,3,9,14,1,3,5,14,1,2),
            second=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),
            PRICE1=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,127.47,127.47,127.47,127.47,NA,NA),
        PRICE2=c(127.49,127.48,127.58,127.46,NA,NA,NA,NA,127.48,127.48), 
            dPRICE1=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA), 
            dPRICE2=c(0,0,0,1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
            )
```

I have a potential solution to this problem but it's very "expensive" in terms of memory. The solution was to create a column for every exchange within the group bSIDE, and than compare it row by row. This solution consumes a lot of memory, which I don't want as the data table may reach even 9 million of observations.

Thank you!

Comment: I struggle to understand the rules in particular the *"or within the group bSIDE=0"* parts; why "or"? I don't understand within which groups you want to compare `PRICE1` and `PRICE2`. Per `bSIDE` *and* `EX`? But then you seem to compare `bSIDE = 0` prices with `bSIDE = 1` prices so that doesn't make sense to me. I also don't understand your expected output which has two `PRICE1` columns. Is that a typo?

Comment: Hey. I thought that by saying within that particular group (bSIDE) would help to understand it better or it would be easier. Though, it is not necessary to have that particular rule. So the point is to compare PRICE1 in EX1 with all the rows (all PRICE2 posted by every single EX) within a second (I forgot to specify this rule). Not sure I make myself a bit more clear. And lastly yes there is a typo with PRICE1 that appear 2. Thank you

Comment: I have just edited. I hope that it is a bit more clear now. Thank you for the points you made.

Comment: No sorry, this is still not clear to me. So you want to compare `PRICE1` with `PRICE2` (and vice-versa) for every `EX` and `second` combination. But you don't have matching entries for every `EX` and `second` combination; for example, you don't have matching `PRICE1`/`PRICE2` entries for `second=0` and `EX=9` nor for `second=0` and `EX=5`. What what exactly are your *groups* here?

Comment: Exactley I don't have. The idea is to compare PRICE1 of EX=1 with PRICE2 in any single EX that appear for PRICE2 within the group second, such that if at least once the condition is met, I should have a dummy equal to 1 for that particular EX in PRICE1. And the same applies for PRICE1 of EX=3, it should check  PRICE2 for every single EX within the second. There is no necesary matching entries,not at all. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say I really understood your "rules"; your data format is very strange, and I would recommend taking a step back and rethinking the former because this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Your data somehow has an awkwardly mixed long and wide data format.

That aside, the following reproduces your expected output. I don't claim that this generalises to your larger problem, but perhaps it will get you started.

```
dt[, `:=`(
    dPRICE1 = +(first(PRICE2[EX == 1 & !is.na(PRICE2)]) < PRICE1),
    dPRICE2 = +(first(PRICE1[EX == 1 & !is.na(PRICE1)]) > PRICE2)),
    by = second]
#    bSIDE EX second PRICE1 PRICE2 dPRICE1 dPRICE2
# 1:     0  1      0     NA 127.49      NA       0
# 2:     0  3      0     NA 127.48      NA       0
# 3:     0  9      0     NA 127.58      NA       0
# 4:     0 14      0     NA 127.46      NA       1
# 5:     1  1      0 127.47     NA       0      NA
# 6:     1  3      0 127.47     NA       0      NA
# 7:     1  5      0 127.47     NA       0      NA
# 8:     1 14      0 127.47     NA       0      NA
# 9:     0  1      1     NA 127.48      NA      NA
#10:     0  2      1     NA 127.48      NA      NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess that you are right that this is like an XY problem. I didn't know about the XY problem, but it is nice to know it, just in case, for further questions.

Comment: You're very welcome @Deea; if this answers your question, please consider closing the question by setting the green checkmark next to the answer.